# Select by ID from a list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table of products and a table of categories, I can select by the `ID` of the `Category` like this:

```
var result = db.tblProducts.Where(p => p.tblCategories.Any(c => c.ID == 1));
```

However, I want to be able to select based on a list of Categories:

```
 var catIDs = new List<int>() { 1,2,3 };

 var results = db.tblProducts.Where(r => r.tblCategories.Any(t => catIDs.Contains(t.ID)));
```

I get the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Presumably because I am using `Contains` to compare entities to local variables. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: try `IEnumerable<Int32> catIDs = new List<int>() { 1,2,3 };`

Comment: Try with an Array instead of a generic List.

Comment: I dont think using `Contains` per se causes this error, more that you are using it in a nested expression. I tried a simpler one using Contains and dont get errors. `companies.Where(c => br.Contains(c.BranchId));`

Comment: You could use `Any` instead of `Contains`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try create `Expression` from values. F.e.:

```
static Expression MakeOrExpression<T, P>(Expression<Func<T, P>> whatToCompare, IEnumerable<P> values)
{
    Expression result = Expression.Constant(true);

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        var comparison = Expression.Equal(whatToCompare, Expression.Constant(value));
        result = Expression.Or(result, comparison);
    }

    return result;
}
```

How to use:

```
var results = db.tblProducts.Where(r => r.tblCategories.Any(MakeOrExpression(t => t.ID, catIDs)));
```

The method `MakeOrExpression` will create an expression `t.ID == 1 || t.ID == 2 || t.ID == 3` for list `{ 1, 2, 3 }` dynamically, and then EF will translate it to SQL condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
var catIDs = new List<int>() { 1,2,3 };

var results = db.tblProducts.Where(r => catIDs.Any(c => c == r.tblCategories.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query=from p in db.tblProducts
          from c in p.tblCategories
          where catIDs.Contains(c.ID)
          select p;
```

If at least one of the categories of the product is in the `catIDs` list, then the product will be seleted.

Another option could be start by the categories (I'm guessing you have a many to many relationship between `Product` and `Category` and you have a collections of products in your `Category` entity):

```
var query=db.tblCategories.Where(c => catIDs.Contains(c.ID)).SelectMany(c=>c.tblProducts).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```
var catIDs = new List<int>() { 1,2,3 };
var results = db.tblCategories
  .Where(t => catIDs.Contains(t.ID))
  .SelectMany(t => t.tblProducts)
  .Distinct();
```